# Transport failed when deploying to AWS China

Tags: 2013-sp1, deployer

When publishing content to a HTTP Deployer in AWS China we always get a transport failed error.

The logs show:

```
2015-10-04 16:51:02,481 ERROR HTTPSTransportConnector - Unable to execute HTTP POST
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_45]
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.write(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:153) ~[httpcore.jar:4.1.4]
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:114) ~[httpcore.jar:4.1.4]
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody.writeTo(FileBody.java:105) ~[httpmime.jar:4.1.3]
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipart.doWriteTo(HttpMultipart.java:206) ~[httpmime.jar:4.1.3]
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipart.writeTo(HttpMultipart.java:224) ~[httpmime.jar:4.1.3]
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity.writeTo(MultipartEntity.java:183) ~[httpmime.jar:4.1.3]
    at org.apache.http.entity.HttpEntityWrapper.writeTo(HttpEntityWrapper.java:96) ~[httpcore.jar:4.1.4]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper$EntityWrapper.writeTo(EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper.java:108) ~[httpclient.jar:4.1.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.entity.EntitySerializer.serialize(EntitySerializer.java:120) ~[httpcore.jar:4.1.4]
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:264) ~[httpcore.jar:4.1.4]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.sendRequestEntity(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:224) ~[httpclient.jar:4.1.3]
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:255) ~[httpcore.jar:4.1.4]
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123) ~[httpcore.jar:4.1.4]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:647) ~[httpclient.jar:4.1.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:464) ~[httpclient.jar:4.1.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820) ~[httpclient.jar:4.1.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754) ~[httpclient.jar:4.1.3]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732) ~[httpclient.jar:4.1.3]
    at com.tridion.transport.connection.connectors.HTTPSTransportConnector.send(HTTPSTransportConnector.java:384) ~[cd_transport.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.transport.connection.connectors.TransportPoolConnector.send(TransportPoolConnector.java:92) [cd_transport.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.transport.workers.TransportSender.call(TransportSender.java:78) [cd_transport.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.transport.workers.TransportSender.call(TransportSender.java:27) [cd_transport.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_45]
```

It appears to be connected to the size of the package, but not with regards to to HTTP Deployer itself, as this has generous httpRuntime and requestLimits in web.config.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>         
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime executionTimeout="1800" maxRequestLength="2048000" />
    </system.web>   
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
        <requestFiltering>                                                              
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2097152000" />                                              
        </requestFiltering>
        </security>     
    </system.webServer>    
</configuration>
```

If I publish a small category this succeeds, but just the homepage produces a 25MB package and this always fails.

I've already increased the SendTimeout in cd_transport_conf.xml.

What is actually resetting the connection - IIS, Windows?

I see from [other posts](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/11666/unable-to-execute-http-post-transport-service-after-a-lot-of-polling-attempts), other people have moved to a FTP deployer - is this the accepted solution?

Comment: can you share the configuration in the `web.config`?

Comment: Bart - updated with Deployer web.config

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This *might* have something to do with the [default connection timeout limit](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/sitedefaults/limits) in IIS. You could to increase that if posting data takes longer than 2 minutes. Next, also set the [executionTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(v=vs.85).aspx) attribute, to ensure there's enough time to upload.

You could move to use FTP as transport protocol, but the same configuration will apply.

Comment: Thanks Raimond - Ill check the default connection timeout, I've already set the executionTimeout,